# Vim 9 and Emmet % key for navigation in html no longer seems to work

Tags: gvim, plugin-emmet-vim

On gVim I find that the % key doesn't work with html files although it does work in CSS files. In HTML files with an extension of .html it seems to do nothing. If the cursor is placed on a div tag pressing % should take it to matching end div tag as it did with Vim 8.

The main difference is that I have reinstalled and upgraded Linux and am using a fresh install of Vim 9 (with the Linux install) instead of Vim 8. Is there anything I need to know to get this working again?

Comment: Maybe should you explain what do you expect the `%` key too (go to the ending/starting tag?). May be a short example would help?

Comment: Why did you reopen that question and why does the UI tells me that I retracted my vote? OP, use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/review-reopen

Comment: Can you reproduce this without plugins?